# Failed to deploy artifacts

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

When I try to deploy my application, I got this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project acme-db: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.acme:acme-db:jar:0.8.1 from/to artifactory.acme.com (http://artifactory.acme.com/libs-release-local): Access denied to: http://artifactory.acme.com/libs-release-local/com/acme/acme-db/0.8.1/acme-db-0.8.1.jar, ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to verify your credentials in MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml section servers

```
<server>
  <id>nexus</id>
  <username>deploy</username>
  <password>123456</password>
</server>
```

Id must match with id in distribution management in your pom.xml

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <url>...</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```